# How do I ingest data from a CSV file stored on OneDrive into a Kusto temp table?

Tags: csv, azure-data-explorer, data-ingestion, ingest

I have an Excel file people use to edit data outside Azure Data Explorer (Kusto). What is the Kusto code I would use to ingest this data as needed into Kusto query?

So far it seems I need to use:

.create table  (Name:type, Name:type)

to create a table.

If my CSV file is stored in OneDrive, what is the syntax to fill the table? Assume the file name is Sample.csv.

Answer (score 2):

OneDrive location is not supported directly by Azure Data Explorer. However there are other options:

1. [Using ingestion commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-from-storage) - you will need to place the files first in Azure Storage.
2. [One Click Ingestion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-one-click) - is a feature of the [Web Explorer](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/) tool, it will also can create the table for you. you can either download the files to your local computer or place it in Azure storage.
3. Using [Import data from local file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/tools/kusto-explorer#importing-a-local-file-into-a-kusto-table) feature of [Kusto Explorer (Windows client)](http://aka.ms/ke) (only works for local files)